# C# , xml parsing. get data between tags

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string :

```
responsestring = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<upload><image><name></name><hash>SOmetext</hash>"
```

How can i get the value between

```
<hash> and </hash>
```

?

My attempts :

```
responseString.Substring(responseString.LastIndexOf("<hash>") + 6, 8); // this sort of works , but won't work in every situation.
```

also tried messing around with xmlreader , but couldn't find the solution.

ty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Others have suggested LINQ to XML solutions, which is what I'd use as well, if possible.

If you're stuck with .NET 2.0, use `XmlDocument` or even `XmlReader`.

But *don't* try to manipulate the raw string yourself using `Substring` and `IndexOf`. Use an XML API of *some* description. Otherwise you **will** get it wrong. It's a matter of using the right tool for the job. Parsing XML properly is a significant chunk of work - work that's already been done.

Now, just to make this a full answer, here's a short but complete program using your sample data:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string response = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<upload><image><name></name><hash>Some text</hash></image></upload>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response);

        foreach (XElement hashElement in doc.Descendants("hash"))
        {
            string hashValue = (string) hashElement;
            Console.WriteLine(hashValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously that will loop over *all* the `hash` elements. If you only want one, you could use `doc.Descendants("hash").Single()` or `doc.Descendants("hash").First()` depending on your requirements.

Note that both the conversion I've used here and the `Value` property will return the concatenation of *all* text nodes within the element. Hopefully that's okay for you - or you could get just the first text node which is a direct child if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
var a = from hash in doc.Descendants("hash")
        select hash.Value;
```

you will need System.Core and System.Xml.Linq assembly references

Answer (score 1):

var val = XElement.Parse();

val.Descendants(...).Value

Answer (score 1):

Get your xml well formed and escape the double quotes with backslash. Then apply the following code

```
 XDocument resp = XDocument.Parse("<hash>SOmetext</hash>");

       var r= from element in resp.Elements()
           where element.Name == "hash"
           select element;


    foreach (var item in r)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an xmlreader and/or xpath queries to get all desired data.

Comment: could you elaborate please. I am completely unfamiliar with xml

Comment: See the answer from Vinay below this.

Comment: @ u have a beautiful mustache

Comment: THNX! @Jenny. Questions and answers should be more beautiful!!

Answer (score 0):

XmlReader_Object.ReadToFollowing("hash");

**string value = XmlReader_Object.ReadInnerXml();**