# Parsing generic tags in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I need to parse text that uses various custom tags within it, for instance:

`<tag>example</tag>`

Everything I see on here dealing with parsing tagged stuff has some premade format (like HTML) so has a library dedicated explicitly to it.  Does C# have anything that can deal with custom tags like this?  Or is the ol' "iterate through the characters and do it yourself" the best I can hope for?

edit: These tags do appear randomly in otherwise normal text, I only need to locate them or extract what is contained in them

Ugh, I can't comment!  I've deactivated my addons (using latest firefox), but it is no avail.  Clicking comment does nothing, only edit works.  Damn, this is frustrating.  I can't even view the newer comments that are coming in past the first 5!

Comment: Is the text valid XML? That could make things easier.

Comment: read this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Is your whole text in an xml format or do these tags appear randomly.

Comment: @vittore - Why link to that? He hasn't mentioned RegEx in the question at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# , xml parsing. get data between tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810340/c-xml-parsing-get-data-between-tags)

Comment: @ConradFrix - It is not clear to me that these are duplicates, as the OP is not asking about XML, but _tags_ within text.

Comment: @Oded On a second read I'd say you're probably right. Perhaps its more similar to parsing Markdown. e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888985/what-markdown-c-library-should-i-use

Comment: @ConradFrix - Possibly, however, a question can be original, you know ;)

Comment: Ugh, had to use IE to comment.  It's not really markdown because markdown appears to use the same sequence of chars for open and closing.  This will always be in the format of < alphanumeric tag > that is then closed with the \.  So, yes, it is fairly similar to HTML but I don't want to wrangle with some huge HTML library for something relatively simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it is an HTML parser that deals with badly formed HTML, but you should be able to use it to query custom elements as well.